# Book or reference material for UML

Tags: java, uml

I have about four years of experience as a Java developer. I'm planning to get myself involved in the world of UML. Can anyone suggest some good books and reference material for UML?

Comment: Typical poll question detected, CW please.

Comment: ["Applying UML and patterns" by Craig Larman](http://www.amazon.com/Applying-UML-Patterns-Introduction-Object-Oriented/dp/0131489062/ref=dp_ob_title_bk)

Answer (score 5):

[UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020165783X), by Martin Fowler.

I have it here, and it's a very good introduction. Actually, it was a "required reading material" for my university, so can be thought of as a textbook as well.

Answer (score 1):

Book Applying UML And Patterns

http://www.craiglarman.com/wiki/index.php?title=Book_Applying_UML_and_Patterns

I used it during my study

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [The Unified Modeling Language User Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201571684), written by the creators of UML, the "Three Amigos" of software engineering (Grady Booch, Ivar Jacobson and James Rumbaugh).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [UML Resource Page](http://www.uml.org/) of the OMG. Among other resources, this page has links to the latest [UML specifications](http://www.omg.org/technology/documents/modeling_spec_catalog.htm#UML).

There are plenty of good books available as well:

- [The Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321245628) - Rumbaugh, Jacobson, and Booch
- [The Unified Modeling Language User Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321267974) - Booch, Rumbaugh, and Jacobson
- [UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687) - Martin Fowler

Answer (score 0):

I am currently reading:

> Object-oriented Systems analysis and design using UML

By Simon Bennett

It is given as indicative reading on my degree course, and has genuinely helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Don't read any book because all these guys just talk about UML but not about real life.

I would recommend to manually code and then reverse your code into a class diagram. You can also reverse a sequence diagram from your methods. 
Don't do more and certainy not read books because it is a waste of time :-)

Comment: Reading books on UML is a "waste of time"?